# Is an apostrophe needed in "children's discounts"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

I've written:

> Special offer: For a limited period (to celebrate the launch of our
> saunas in Chalet Harriet 1 & 2) we are offering our free children's
> discounts on both chalets for 15th December and 22nd December.

I particularly want to know if it's "childrens" or "children's" (with or without the apostrophe) and if the brackets above work?

Comment: You’ve still got a problem with “free and discounts”  if you are saying that the discount you are offering is the “free children” discount, then it might be clearer as “We are offering our “children-stay-free” discount on both...  But more like *real* ad copy would be: “Book one of these chalets for Dec 15th or Dec 22nd and your children stay free!”

Answer (score 0):

It's "children's". "Childrens" is never correct because "children" is already plural. To show something possessed by children, the apostrophe-s is required. IOW, the way you have it in your original text is correct.

For words that are singular but for which you want to show possession by more than one of them, such as fees paid to many lawyers, you would make "lawyer" plural by adding an s, and then make it possessive by adding the apostrophe at the END.

"The settlement money was almost entirely consumed by the lawyers' fees."

Comment: It would be children's if the sentence was otherwise correct, but it isn't. *We are offering our free children's discounts on both chalets...* would mean that there is an established discount that is given to children for free, and as a special offer it is available on both chalets on the dates given. The discount isn't given to children, though, and it isn't given for free - it is a 'children go free' discount.

Comment: It could also be parsed as a discount that's possessed by free children. The apostrophe aside, the sentence has much larger issues.